# Javascript: How to generate monthly dates?

Tags: javascript, date

I need to calculate monthly dates, that is, given a particular date, generate dates for the next 2 years for example. I came up with the following code:

```
var d = new Date( '2007-12-31' );
  d.setMonth( d.getMonth() + 1 );
  for (var i = 1; i<24; i++){
    var newdate = d.getDate() + "-" + d.getMonth()+i + '-' + d.getFullYear()
    print(newdate);
  }
```

However, this is producing:

```
(...)
31-06-2008  (ok)
31-07-2008  (ok)
31-08-2008  (ok)
31-09-2008  (ok)
31-010-2008 (error, 3 characters for month) 
31-011-2008 (error, 3 characters for month)
31-012-2008 (error, 3 characters for month)
31-013-2008 (error, should be 31-01-2009)
31-014-2008 (error, should be 28-02-2009)
```

Please, is there any way of producing monthly dates considering some months are 30 or 31 days and February is 28 or 29 depending on the years? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var d = new Date(2007, 11, 31);
d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
for(i=1; i<24; i++) { 
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth()+1);
    d.setDate(1);
    d.setDate(d.getDate()-1);
    document.write(d.getDate() + "-" + ("0" + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' + d.getFullYear() + '<br />');
    d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
    }
```

1. Step forward one month
2. Set the date to first of the month
3. Step back one day (last day of previous month)
4. Write the date (prepend 0 and use slice() to get the last two characters)
5. Step forward one day to return to next month
6. Increment the month

Answer (score 3):

You got sybmol like that "011" because of "0" + 11 in `js` it equals 011. So you should convert like this `+(d.getMonth())` to number before sum.

This code should be correct:

```
var d = new Date( '2007-12-31' );
  d.setMonth( d.getMonth() + 1 );
  for (var i = 1; i<24; i++){
    var newdate = d.getDate() + "-" + (+(d.getMonth()) + i) + '-' + d.getFullYear()
    console.log(newdate);
  }
```

Comment: 2 years = 24 months ^^

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
var d = new Date();

for (var i = 0, size = 24; i < size; i++){
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
  console.log(d.getDate() + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + d.getFullYear())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After first 12 months, you  need to increment year and reset month to 0. You keep trying to increment month beyond the 12 months.